# Jmeter - Generating summary report for load testing (multiple users)

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am using `jmeter` for load and performance testing. I am able to successfully generate summary report by using only one user as load. But, if I want to generate summary report for multiple users (say 100 users), how can I configure `jmeter` GUI to generate summary report?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JMeter doesn't care about number of users. The only thing to consider: **don't use JMeter GUI to perform load test itself**.

The easiest approach to use:

1. Configure your test as required. JMeter GUI can be used at this stage.
2. Run your test in non-GUI console mode as follows:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/test/results.jtl
   ```
3. After load test open JMeter GUI (even empty test plan)
4. Add the listener of your choice, i.e. [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report)
5. Click "Browse" button and open your `/path/to/test/results.jtl`
6. Perform analysis, raise bugs, etc.

Also make sure that you're following other recommendations from [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the Summary Report controller at the top level, just beside (not inside) the Thread Group. Otherways, its scope becomes a single thread, which is not useful.